# TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str but when trying to change var's to str, I get a different error

Tags: python, tetris

So, I'm trying to make a PPS (Pieces Placed Per Second) Calculator For Tetris In Python. However, when I try to divide the time and pieces I get this error:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

And some people on the site say something like "Convert the int to a str!"
But when I do that, I get *this* error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'
```

Here is the code:

```
pieces = input("How many pieces did you place? ")
time = input("How long did you play for? (In Seconds Please!) ")
PPS = " "


def answer():
    PPS = round(str(time) / str(pieces))
    print("Your PPS is: " + PPS)


answer()
```

Please help soon and thanks!

Comment: `pieces` & `time` need to be  numbers when doing calculations on them. When you're doing `"Your PPS is: " + PPS` then PPS is a number - you can't add a number and a string. They both need to be strings. Then you should do a `str(PPS)`

Comment: `input()` returns a string.  therefore `pieces` and `time` are also strings.  it makes no sense to divide a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already fixed the problem. The problem being I needed to change
`Time`
and
`Pieces`
To
`float(time)`
and
`float(pieces)` and it works.

Answer (score 1):

mathematical operations can be performed on numbers, and concatenation is doneon strings...
You can try this:

```py
def answer():
    PPS = round(int(time) / int(pieces))
    print("Your PPS is: " + str(PPS))
```

or:

```py
def answer():
    PPS = round(int(time) / int(pieces))
    print("Your PPS is: {0}".format(PPS))
```

Or you can just: wrap function `int` around the `input`
so it becomes `pieces = int(input("How many pieces did you place? "))`, similar for `time`
and then inside the function:

```py
pieces = int(input("How many pieces did you place? "))
time = int(input("How long did you play for? (In Seconds Please!) "))
PPS = ""

def answer():
    PPS = round(time / pieces)
    print("Your PPS is: " + str(PPS))
```

Comment: doesn't work because the round function need numbers not strings

Comment: The top one helped out, but when I put anything that prints the answer as less than 1, it just says `PPS Is 0.0`